# How to immediate effect on website after changes in less css code?

Tags: css, magento2.4, less-css, less-compilation

I am developing website design on Product listing page by css code in `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less` file
.Whenever I change the css code in above file I have to run `setup:upgrade` and `static:deploy` command. This is time consuming process when you develop design. Any trick that after change the code in less file and reflect immediately without execute commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Grunt you can watch and automatically compile LESS to CSS without having to run any commands.

Once installed run `grunt less` to compile or `grunt watch` to watch files and automatically compile.

For full indepth instructions and more commands see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html

Comment: Appreciated, Thanks @BenCrook for save the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Live Reload and Grunt.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Comment: @AneesAhmed Thank you